# Построить список, объединяющий два списка без повторений

Tags: prolog

Здравствуйте! Даны два списка, имеющие ненулевое пересечение. Построить список, включающий все элементы указанных двух списков без повторений.
В моем коде выдает ошибку о недопустимом типе в следующей строке:

```
new_list([H|T],[Y|Tail],List):- not(member(Y,[H|T])),not(member(H,Tail)),new_list(T,Tail,[[Y,H]|List]).
```

Код программы представлен ниже:

```
domains 
list1, list2, list3 = integer*
predicates
   new_list(list1, list2, list3)
   member(integer, list1)
clauses
member(H, [H|Tail]).
member(X, [H|Tail]):- member(X,Tail).
new_list(List1,[Y|Tail],List):- member(Y,List1),new_list(List1,Tail,[Y|List]).
new_list([H|T],[Y|Tail],List):- not(member(Y,[H|T])),not(member(H,Tail)),new_list(T,Tail,[[Y,H]|List]).
new_list([],[],List).


goal
     L1=[1,5,3,-6,8,-4],L2=[4, 6, 5,7,0,8],
     new_list(L1,L2,Res).
```

Не пойму, почему ругается на тип. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

> Ошибка: E;Test_Goal, pos: 651, 505 Type error: Illegal variable type for this position

Comment: вероятно, union?

Comment: добавь в вопрос полный текст ошибки

Answer (score 1):

Объединение списков получается операцией union:

```
union([1, 5, 3,-6, 8,-4], [4, 6, 5, 7, 0, 8], X).
X = [1, 3, -6, -4, 4, 6, 5, 7, 0, 8]
```

Comment: а эта операция не создает повторения, если в двух списках одинаковые элементы?

Comment: Обратите внимание на 5 и 8. Нет, не создаёт. Она работает со списками, как с множествами.

Comment: Спасибо)) Хотя все-таки интересно, почему он ругался на тип, потому как Tail - список, как и указано в предикате

Comment: @tryuf, возможно причина в определении типов: зачем делать три разных типа? сделай один `list1 = integer*` и используй `new_list(list1, list1, list1)`. собственно скорее всего тут и проблема: member только list1 принимает, а ты в него list2 пытаешься передать

Comment: поняла, спасибо